# node js async await timing out on heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, async-await

my code is running fine when I run it locally, but when I push it to Heroku I keep getting timed out, status 503 and error code H12. I've seen other users asking about this when they use async/await but none of their solutions have made sense or helped me. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do in my code to make it run faster or not time out on Heroku. Any help is appreciated!

```
  (async () => {
    posts = await instagramPosts(userName);

    posts.forEach(function(post) {
      photos.push(post.media);
      shortcodes.push(post.shortcode);
    });

    console.log(shortcodes);

    res.render("home", {userName: userName, photos: photos, shortcodes: shortcodes});
  })();
```

Edit: I am also getting  this error, but I am unsure what it means:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
```

Comment: `console.log` is slow. I'd start by removing that. Beyond that, it's pretty hard to say what the problem could be. How many elements is `posts`? Ah, after you posted your error, it looks like you have some code that's throwing an exception inside your `async` func. Use `try`-`catch` to see what it is.

Comment: I'll try that. `posts` has a maximum of 12 elements.

Comment: Then forget it, that's not the problem and likely neither is `console.log`.

Comment: would i run into errors when I run the code locally? or do i have to try and try-catch them in the code?

Comment: If you're using promises that can throw, you need to catch them like the error says.